# Small red brick wall area to hold L brackets

Tags: walls, table, brackets

Refer to image below, I would like to know are my wall and the custom build L brackets able to hold around 50kg includes table top.

Ps: the L brackets is flat not those angle L 
[image: Diagram of planned table]

Here's a picture of where I want to install the table:
[image]

Comment: It's pretty tough to figure out what you're planning (e.g. mixing metric and imperial), but it looks like you only have 4" of bracket along the wall to support over a hundred pounds. That's a pretty short lever arm to carry a significant weight.

Comment: i know it is too short. If it goes to long will become ugly. I will upload actual picture later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support loads at the edge of the table, your brackets apply a torque to the wall. Let's say you're using two brackets, and 3/4 of the 50kg is on the edge of the 25" deep table (maybe it isn't, but someday someone's going to lean on it...)

The top anchor bolt in the bracket pulls out from the wall, and the bottom edge of the bracket pushes in, generating the needed torque. The brackets are 4" tall, so let's say the distance from the top bolt to the bottom edge is 3". That means the 50kg weight at the table edge will be multiplied by (25" / 3"), or about a factor of 8, meaning the brackets will be pulling on those top bolts with a force of about 400kg. Yes, there are two brackets, but that's still 200kg per bolt, pulling straight out. Even if the brackets could hold that, the bolts won't.

You need to increase the distance between that top and bottom support points. You could do this by making the bracket taller, by having the bracket extend above the table somehow, or just by hanging the front edge of the table from cables extending up to the sides of the windows. Otherwise, it may be pretty, but it will be pretty breakable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Any bracket with those ratios should have a gusset added to it. If you look at any factory made longer L-brackets that long you will see they are supported by a gusset.

The reason is even if the steel you are using holds the load it will be springy out at the edge away from the wall. Hence the gusset to give it a more solid feel.

The other options is to build your brackets with angle instead of flat steel. These will have an inherent strength that flat steel doesn't.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank for reply . Yes. I know. I want to test without gusset 1st because the total weight won't over 50kg. If cannot then i will add gusset on it.  So how about the brick wall?  Is it enough to hold ?Because it is just 7.3 inches from top to the L brackets.

Comment: When you say "brick wall" do you mean concrete block or actual bricks. And is this an interior wall?

Comment: Yes interior wall and actual bricks. Here is the reference https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQeSJLT-674NCCDUPO1WZWNYAKE8FdC5oBSBBaQwiQkr5inyTkm

Comment: Well, without seeing the wall I would just say that if the top of it is not locked in somehow or bearing a load then it will be much weaker. The way to tear down a brick wall is from the top down. A free standing brick wall's weakest part for lateral strength would at the top in the center of the wall. Those bricks can easily be knocked off.

Comment: Sorry, i should use real picture instead. here it is  https://goo.gl/photos/PN5RmbaWSKhR5Nkf9

Comment: Yeah, I have to agree with Daniel. For the placement you have on that wall the brick will probably be plenty strong if it is more than 28 days old. However, the anchors could fail by pulling out or chip the brick around the anchor, before the brick itself comes out of the wall. The shelf would probably be fine for a short time but with regular use the top anchors will begin to work loose. Even with a gusset on the steel to support the shelf that won't change the tension on the upper anchors. Perhaps you should consider having the brackets extend above the shelf up to the window moulding.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say put a short section of Angle Iron on the right wall & then put both of your L-brackets under the left side to have just the left float. This will provide a much more secure table & minimize tension upon the bricks.